# Parse an OCR scanned PDF document output file and return values for defined terms in the document

Tags: regex, powershell, notepad++

I need to parse through an OCR output of a PDF file (contract agreements), and search for particular defined terms (e.g. "Company", "Effective Data", "Agreement", etc..). I would like to be able to search through the document and return the term that I'm searching for (e.g. "Company") and also the string that precedes the defined term. The defined term (e.g. "Company" includes the ""'s where it is defined, and should only occur once in the document. The string that I need to retrieve that precedes the defined term may be multiple words (e.g. ACME Chemicals, Inc.).

Looking for recommendations on how I could handle this either in PowerShell or Notepad++ editor.

Comment: Could you please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: I use [PDFClown](https://pdfclown.org/) for that.

Comment: Sample input:"This Work Order #1 ("Work Order") is entered into as of September 25, 2015 (the "Effective Date") and
shall be governed by the terms of the Master Services Agreement dated September 4, 2015 (the "Agreement") in effect between ACME, Inc. ("ACME") and Services Unlimited, Inc. ("Vendor"), and shall be
attached to and made a part of the Agreement.

Comment: Desired Sample Output:

Comment: Sample Output:
"Work Order":This Work Order #1
"Effective Date":September 25, 2015
"Vendor":Services Unlimited, Inc.
And so on, for other defined terms that are identified in the document (if present)

Comment: The key thing that I'm trying to do is to scan through the OCR PDF for a list of defined terms (just a few of which provided above), and return them in a CSV file that essentially has two fields (1:the defined term, 2: the string of text prior to the defined term). I realize that part of the challenge will be that the "string of text" can be of variable length so I may not know how many "words" to grab.